# Modal opens but does not display the content - ngx-smart-modal

Tags: modal-dialog, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 with version 5.2.9 and I'm using ngx-smart-modal and when I open Modal does not present the content and is very close to the top and reduced, the attached image is attached.

```
const reasons = '<h1>Reasons</h1>';
this.ngxSmartModalService.setModalData(this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(reasons), 'reasonsModal');
this.ngxSmartModalService.getModal('reasonsModal').open();
```

```html
<ngx-smart-modal #reasonsModal identifier="reasonsModal" (onDismiss)="clearModal()" (onClose)="clearModal()">
  <div *ngIf="reasonsModal.hasData()" [innerHTML]="reasonsModal.getData()">
    <pre>{{reasonsModal.getData}}</pre>
  </div>
  <button (click)="reasonsModal.close()">Closes</button>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

[image: Error in image]

Comment: Hi can you provide a link of your complete source code please like github or beter stackblitz?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this project was closed and I will not have to work on it, but thanks for the attention.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The reason probably is the missed parenthesis on the function:

```
{{reasonsModal.getData}}
```

When actually should be:

```
{{reasonsModal.getData()}}
```